# Conditional filtering for results in a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Is it possible to filter for results in a pivot table conditionally?  I can only find information about conditional formatting (data bars, for example) and am interested instead in filtering conditionally.  For example, students take classes in Q1, Q2 and Q3.  I'd like to filter for test results to compare students taking a 2-term course in Q1 and Q3 (a gap between classes) and those that take the 2 courses one after the other, Q1 and Q2, or Q2 and Q3.

So far, I've only tried to arrange my table fields in a variety of ways, but have been unsuccessful.  I'd like to avoid having to paste the values into another sheet and grind through a bunch of calculations, as I have a LOT of different scenarios to consider.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your question (some raw data would probably help) but adding a flag (say S for split) to those taking the classes in Q1 and Q3 may facilitate differentiating these from the rest in a pivot table.